# Creating a variable array in sql

Tags: sql

Right now my code looks like:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table 
 WHERE Id in ('123','456','789')
```

And I want to make the list a variable so that the code would look something like this:

```
Id_list = ('123','456','789')

SELECT * 
  FROM Table 
 WHERE Id in Id_list
```

I'm not super familiar with SQL, I'm sorry if this is obvious or my description uses the wrong terminology. Thanks!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (SQL itself has no array variables.)

Comment: @jarlh: that's not entirely true. The SQL standard **does** define arrays

Comment: What DBMS are you using (MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, etc)? While an array is the SQL99 standard, not all DBMS implement it and the ones that do have slightly different flavors of it.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In mysql, mysql sever:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT '1' 
        UNION SELECT '2' 
        UNION SELECT '3' 
        UNION SELECT '4') as Array
```

Answer (score 1):

a possible solution is to put the array in a VARCHAR:

```
Id_list VARCHAR2(500)= '123,456,789';

SELECT * 
  FROM Table 
 WHERE INSTR(Id_list,Id) > 0
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Version :

```
--Test Data
CREATE TABLE TestTable
    ([ID] nvarchar(20))
;

INSERT INTO TestTable
    ([ID])
VALUES
    ('123'),
    ('456'),
    ('789')
;

--Use With As
with arr_st as (
  select '123' ID union all
  select '456' ID union all
  select '789' ID
)
SELECT * FROM TestTable 
WHERE Id in (select * from arr_st)
```

Result:
[image]

---

[SQL Fiddle LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fbba7/2/0) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fbba7/2/0

Hope It help you :)

Answer (score 0):

it's sql server method

```
select * into #Array  --it's sql server temp table
from (
  select '123' [value] union all
  select '456' [value] union all
  select '789' [value]
) T
;  

SELECT * FROM YourTable 
WHERE YourColumn in (select * from #Array)
```

use temp table like collection in sql

Comment: Please explain your lines of code so other users can understand its functionality. Thanks!